# How to check for network connection in BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to identify the internet connection in BrightScript using scenegraph. If there is no internet, I wanted show some error screen on internet goes off.

I checked in Roku's documentation, I didn't find much coding samples there.

I found that we can use, `GetInfo().linkStatus` to get the network status

But I want to add observer to get the status everytime whenever status changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check your message port for linkStatus events on BrightScript and reflect its state into your SG scene.

Here is an example:

Add a field in **scene.xml** to be your link status interface between brs and SG, such as

```
<field id="offline" type="boolean" value="false" alwaysNotify="true" onChange="onOfflineChanged" />
```

Then, in **main.brs**, create an roDeviceInfo instance (in case haven't one already) and assign the same message port you are already using:

```
m.deviceInfo = CreateObject("roDeviceInfo")
m.deviceInfo.setMessagePort(m.port)
```

Enable link status events on your roDeviceInfo instance

```
m.deviceInfo.EnableLinkStatusEvent(true)
```

to be able to receive `roDeviceInfoEvent` events when waiting for new messages from your roMessagePort.

Each time you get a message from your port, check its type and assign the new linkStatus value to the scene field created in the first step

```
if msgType = "roDeviceInfoEvent" and msg.isStatusMessage() then scene.offline = not msg.getInfo().linkStatus
```

The callback should be declared in the **scene.brs** file

```
function onOfflineChanged()
    if(m.top.offline)
       ' your code here
    end if
end function
```

and that's it.

For extra correctness, you should check its status as soon as the app is launched. You could do so with

```
scene.offline = not m.deviceInfo.GetLinkStatus()
```

before entering the while(true) loop.

Comment: I'll check this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event on the while loop and detect if the Roku Device is connected to Internet, also you need to add a functional field on the mainScene

```
sub main()
    screen = createObject("roSGScreen")
    port = createObject("roMessagePort")
    screen.SetMessagePort(m.port)
    scene = screen.createScene("mainScene")

    deviceInfo = createObject("roDeviceInfo")
    deviceInfo.setMessagePort(port)
    deviceInfo.enableLinkStatusEvent(true)

    screen.Show()

    while(true)
        msg = wait(0, m.port)
        msgType = type(msg)

        if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
            if msg.IsScreenClosed() then return
        else if  msgType = "roDeviceInfoEvent"
            if msg.isStatusMessage()
                scene.callFunc("handleLinkStatusEvents",{})
            end if
       end if
end while
```

end sub